# Mock all methods that start with a specific string

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I'm trying to mock a class which has a lot of "fluent" setters and I was wondering if there's an easy way to mock all of them in one go.

For example I have code to be tested like:

```
$object->setId(1)
       ->setVersion(1)
       ->setText('a');
```

Instead of mocking each setter individually I was trying to do something like:

```
$mock->expects($this->any())
     ->method($this->stringStartsWith('set'))
     ->willReturn($mock);
```

However this doesn't seem to be working. All setters are returning `null` which (I think) means they are not matched with this behaviour.

Is this even possible and if so what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: Perhaps use reflection and loop over all of the methods applying a mock to those that match.

Comment: @NigelRen I guess that's not an unreasonable thing to do if there's no built-in support for this.